# Do I need an application factory in my Flask-SQLAlchemy project?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making a project which does two things: 1) scrape data from a webpage on an hourly basis and  insert this data into a database
2) serve data in json format for a given query

I can get it to work when everything (views, models, db.session.add() etc.) is  within an app.py file. However this is not ideal and I would like to separate it out.

Once I have a working project, I want to set it up on a server to automatically run the webscraping/database populating functionality (1) while also responding to http requests (2).

For this, do I need to go down the route of making an application factory and considering the application context, or is this not necessary? What would a minimal project layout look like/what files would I need, in order to separate out my app.py file (and use an application factory).

Answer (score 3):

Separating models from `app.py` would look something like this.

models.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Post(db.Model):
    ...

class User(db.Model):
    ...
```

app.py:

```
from models import db, Post, User

app = Flask(__name__)
db.init_app(app)
```

You could leave the views in `app.py` if the application is not too large.

The scraping can be done separately from the Flask app. The Flask app just displays whatever is in the database. The scraping is done via a Python script, which updates the db from time to time. This could be scheduled to run on the server via `cron`.